# Can I use {{variable name}} in ng-model on angular 1.x

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this source

```
<tr ng-repeat="value in item.info_group">
                                <td class="text-center"><input type="radio" value="{{value.carrier}}" ng-model="item.select_carrier" ng-change="calcAllPrice()"></td>
                                <td class="text-center">{{value.carrier}}</td>
                                <td class="text-center">
                                  <select class="form-control" ng-model="item.info_group['{{value.carrier}}']">
                                    <option value="{{carrier_info.carrier_type}}" ng-repeat="carrier_info in value.value">{{carrier_info.carrier_type}}({{carrier_info.charge}})</option>
                                  </select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
```

I wanna use {{variable}} in ng-model like ng-model="item.info_group['{{value.carrier}}']"

Can I use like that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need the curly brackets, you can just do it like this:

```
ng-model="item.info_group[value.carrier]"
```

Answer (score 1):

As Michael said, you don't need the curly brackets inside `ng-model`. The reason being that the `{{var}}` syntax is used for one-way data-binding (i.e. `$scope` -> view). The `ng-model` directive sets up a two-way binding on form elements (i.e. `$scope` -> view *and* view -> `$scope`).

In your particular case you want a two way binding on the item from array `item.info_group` with the index `value.carrier` and don't need to use any `{{var}}` syntax to achieve that.